# SQL To Determine Subscribers on a DE but NOT on a List

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I"m trying to write a SQL to determine which subscribers are on Data Extension X but NOT on List ID Y.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
select a.email_address
, a.subscriberkey 
from ent.[listname] a 
left join _subscribers b 
on a.email_address=b.EmailAddress
 where b.EmailAddress IS NULL
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Here's what I've tried so far. 
select a.email_address, a.subscriberkey
from ent.[listname] a
left join _subscribers b on a.email_address=b.EmailAddress
where b.EmailAddress IS NULL

Comment: is this supposed to be checking for just a specific list or for any list (e.g. All subscribers)?

Answer (score 1):

You query is set up to do the inverse of what you want i.e. it will select subscribers present in list Y but not in Data Extension X. To return subscribers in X not present in Y,

```
SELECT a.email_address
, a.subscriberkey 
FROM _subscribers a 
LEFT JOIN ent.[listname] b
on a.email_address=b.EmailAddress
WHERE b.EmailAddress IS NULL
```